# Proving that the sequence $a_n=\frac{2}{2n^2-3}$ is null by the definition of a null sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following question:

> Use the definition of a null sequence to prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ given by $$a_n = \frac{2}{2n^2-3}$$ is null.

I am struggling to see why...

Comment: What do you mean with $a_n=2/2n^2-3$, as it is written, it means $\frac{2}{2n^2}-3$ and this is definitely not a sequence converging to zero (if you intend to say this with `zero sequence`). Please write your questions more carefully and look to the help page here how to format them.

Comment: It's probably $2/(2n^2-3)$.

Comment: Sorry I just edited it with brackets to make it clearer but I can't find the help page to which you are referring.

Comment: What is your definition of the null sequence?And what have you tried already?

Comment: So I have 2/(2n^2-3)<E and I have reduced that down to n>sqrt(1/2(2/E+3)) but it doesn't look like enough working for 7 marks?

Comment: My definition is that modulus an<E for all n>N

Comment: Do I first need to work out the modulus of the sequence, as if n=1 then it's negative?

Answer (score 0):

For every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $k$ such that $\varepsilon>\frac{1}{k}$.

Then for every $n>\sqrt{\frac{2k+3}{2}}$ we have $a_n=\frac{2}{2n^2-3}<\frac{1}{k}<\varepsilon$, and then $a_n\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong with the argument

$\begin{align} 
0 \le \dfrac{2}{2n^2 - 3}  & =  \dfrac{2}{2[(n-2) + 2]^2 - 3}\\
 & = \dfrac{2}{2[(n-2)^2 +4(n-2) + 4] - 3} \\
 & =  \dfrac{2}{2(n-2)^2 +8(n-2) + 5} \\
 &< \dfrac{1}{(n-2)^2}\\
 & < \epsilon \text{ for } n > 2 + \sqrt{ 1/\epsilon}
\end{align}$

Comment: Your inequality $\frac{2}{2n^2-3}<\frac{1}{n^2}$ is not correct.

Comment: @TienKhaPham, thanks for spotting the error.  i think it is fixed now.

Comment: I think you should replace $n+2$ by $n-2$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand these solutions. I don't know what int means or where the k came from. I'm really trying but they both look so different so it's confusing me.